# Multimeter reports voltage but no power?

Tags: ac, filter, fuses, repair, home-automation

I have an Insteon FilterLinc, which is an electrical line filter. It doesn't work. When I connect a lamp to the "filtered" outlet, I get no power. So I stuck multimeter probes into the filtered outlet and it shows voltage, but I am not able to power a lamp or anything from it. I thought it might be the fuse, but I tested both sides of the fuse for continuity and it said there was connection...but I suppose it could be getting a connection from the other way. I'm not sure. What could be happening?

Here is all the information and schematics I could find on the device:

[Overview of the internals](http://s941.photobucket.com/user/EVIL_Teken/media/Insteon/A38ECC81-4A36-4644-ABE9-DB52D724D407_zps5qzyoi0q.jpg.html)

[Schematic](http://home.comcast.net/~gafield/family/gary/electronics/X10_Filter.pdf)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check if the lamp works on the unfiltered outlet or on an entirely independent outlet?  You might have a bad lamp.

Comment: @Barry Yes indeed! Sorry I didn't clarify that. It is a perfectly working lamp. It works on the unfiltered outlet and independent outlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot this, first unplug it (both input and outputs) and short the filtered output momentarily to discharge any charge left on the capacitors.

You should measure virtually a short circuit from the left (neutral) input to each of the two left outputs. Same thing with the right (hot) input wire to each of the two right outputs. If the latter does not measure close to a short circuit you've got a blown fuse.

You can verify by measuring continuity  directly across the fuse with it completely unplugged (inputs and outputs). If it's open, the fuse is gone. You can also look at the back of the PCB and see if one of the inductor wires or one of the input or output wires has a bad solder joint (not altogether unlikely given the large diameter). Or a trace is blown off the board. If your outlet is wired correctly, it's probably a neutral (white) wire or conductor. You can remove the screws, swing the board out and examine it (wiggle the wires and see if anything in the joint moves).

It's not always reliable to measure higher voltages alone without a load because leakage resistance or capacitance can cause non-zero readings.

Answer (score 0):

I am a heating contractor and have performed several jobs over the years. Once I installed an outlet and had 120v but nothing operated. I recently installed a furnace and the old one ran not the new one didnt e cept for a very short time. The pro lem is improper grounding. Sure your meter says it's there but depending on situation and/or equipment being operated it may need a proper ground OR power source.